# Research on chicken that cannot feel pain

Tags: genetics, evolution, artificial-selection

In was having a conversation about the ethics of vegetarianism, and if it is right to cause pain to other animals.

It is then that I stumbled upon the question, that if, just the way chicken and many other animals have currently been cultured or genetically modified (or by any other means) to have certain desirable qualities (from market and demand perspective) such as the fat content, quality of eggs etc., will it be fine to consume chicken if we also, if possible, raise chicken that do not feel any pain at all (if that is defined, or can we define that?).

I realise that this is not philosophy stackexchange, so I would not ask about the ethics of it.

What I want to ask here is this: is such research taking place (anywhere on earth) to develop breeds of chicken that do not feel pain, if yes I would be thankful to know at least the basics, and if not, do you think it is possible in the near future or what possible approach would you contemplate?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, you might want to look at the [NIH page on congenital insensitivity to pain](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition/congenital-insensitivity-to-pain) and consider the effect a similar condition would have on chickens. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: Inability to feel pain seems likely to make an animal accident-prone.

Comment: I used to raise chickens (among lots of other animals.) Chicks peck at anything that stands out, they can't help it. They don't do it to be cruel. If another chick didn't get out of the way when pecked, it would get a bloody or bald spot on it, which would attract more pecks, and further injury, etc. Eventually these chicks die of infection. I've seen it happen a lot to a particular kind of chick (called broilers) bred to grow quickly to market size. Unfortunately, they were also dumber than a box of rocks, and didn't get out of the way. Since I didn't debeak chicks...

Comment: ...the broilers had more than a 50% mortality rate when raised with normal chicks. It was heartbreaking, and I had to isolate the broiler chicks, and never had the heart to eat them though they grew to be very large. They were also very docile, so easy prey for foxes, coyotes, etc. But my point in all this is... pain matters **a lot** to survival. I doubt a chick without pain would have much chance to survive to adulthood.